# Combine some text lines by elements in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, merge

I have some files:

```
file1.txt

[some] "one"

[like] "two"

file2.txt

[some] "test" 

[like] "info"
```

,and so on.

I need to combine them by equal []-elements in each file:

```
file_output.txt

[some] "one" "test"

[like] "two" "info"
```

How i can do that using ruby?

Comment: Working on a solution that doesn't use regexp now, if you still need one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.write('file_output.txt', 
  %w{file1.txt file2.txt}.
    flat_map { |f| File.readlines(f) }.
    map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?).
    map { |l| l.split(' ',2) }.
    group_by(&:first).
    map { |k,v| [k, *v.map(&:last)].join(' ') << "\n" }.
    join("\n")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
.inject({}) do |h, f|
  File.read(f).scan(/^(\[.+?\])\s+(.*)/).each do |k, v|
     (h[k] ||= k).concat(" #{v}")
  end; h
end.values
.tap{|a| File.write("file_output.txt", a.join($/*2))}
```

Comment: `open(f, &:read)` seems like an awkward way to say `File.read(f)`. In Ruby 2, you can just use [`File::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-write) instead of `open(...) {|f| f.write }`